# yii2: chaining relations, filtering and sorting in the gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, relationship

I have a problem over years..

I have an optimized mysql database (the tables includes more fields really) and it seems too hard for me to get a related data across more database tables in Yii2.

**In Palyazo model (1) I want to get the *munkahely_nev* field from Munkahely model (4).**

***megpalyazott_ah (2)* is  many to many table,** the ***allashely (3)* is a many to one**

My final goal is to make searchable and filterable the fields of both the Palyazo and the Munkahely table in the Palyazo index view.

[image: optimized mysql database structure]

Sometimes I make a mysql view (to connect the tables with sql in the mysql server) and generate model, controller, index view with gii (as it would be a regular table, not a mysql view) but I hope there is simplier/nicer way to do it.

In the **Palyazo model** there are three relation:

```
public function getMegpalyazottMunkahely()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Munkahely::className(), ['id' => 'munkahely_id'])->via('allashely');

}

public function getAllashely()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Allashely::className(), ['id' => 'allashely_id'])->via('megpalyazottAh');
}

public function getMegpalyazottAh()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MegpalyazottAh::className(), ['palyazo_id' => 'id']);
}
```

When I write in the **PalyazoSearch model, search() function:**

```
 //I connect just 1-2-3 table (1:palyazo, 2:megpalyazott_ah, 3:allashely)

 $query = Palyazo::find()->innerJoinWith('allashely', true);

 echo "sql: ".$query->createCommand()->sql;

 //I stop the code with die function:

 die();
```

**The output seems to be fine:**

**sql: SELECT `palyazo`.* FROM `palyazo` INNER JOIN `megpalyazott_ah` ON `palyazo`.`id` = `megpalyazott_ah`.`palyazo_id` INNER JOIN `allashely` ON `megpalyazott_ah`.`allashely_id` = `allashely`.`id`**

But when I want to move on (I want to connect the **4th, munkahely table** too with the getMegpalyazottMunkahely  relation),
I modify that line in the **PalyazoSearch model:**:

```
 //I connect just 1-2-3 table (1:palyazo, 2:megpalyazott_ah, 3:allashely, 4:munkahely)
 $query = Palyazo::find()->innerJoinWith('megpalyazottMunkahely', true);
```

The output is:

[image: yii error message: Getting unknown property: app\models\Palyazo::allashely_id]

**HERE IS THE FULL ERRORMESSAGE:**
https://pastebin.com/GX6TGsEe

As you can see on the database structure, **allashely_id field is in the megpalyazott_ah (2nd) table, not is palyazo (1st)..** so I should use **joinWith()** other way to connect the 3rd and the 4th table.

Thank you in advance!

**PS:**
Serghei Leonenco suggested to use the connect only the 2nd table (megpalyazott_ah) :
Palyazo::find()->joinWith('megpalyazottAh');

//and after that check like this:

->andFilterWhere(['like', megpalyazottMunkahely.name',$this->munkahely_nev]);

Thank you Serghei, I tried it but when I try to filter data in name field:

**Column not found: 1054
Unknown column 'megpalyazottMunkahely.munkahely_nev' in 'where clause'**

The SQL being executed was:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM palyazo LEFT JOIN megpalyazott_ah ON palyazo.id = megpalyazott_ah.palyazo_id WHERE (megpalyazottMunkahely.munkahely_nev LIKE '%Fő%') AND (dr LIKE "%%" OR nev LIKE "%%")

The problem is that only 2 connected this way. It this way the fields of the fourth table can't be found for the counting records.

The PalyazoSearch.php looks like this:

```
class PalyazoSearch extends Palyazo
{
    //I create a public variable for filtering, sorting:
    public $munkahely_nev;


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['munkahely_nev'],'safe'],

        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        
        //of course, it's ok, THERE IS NO PROBLEM:
        //$query = Palyazo::find();        
            
        //it is ok, too, THERE IS NO ERROR:
        //$query = Palyazo::find()->joinWith('allashely');        

        //THIS VERSION/LINE MAKES THE ERRORMESSAGE!
        $query = Palyazo::find()->joinWith('megpalyazottMunkahely');        
               
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);


        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'nev', $this->nev]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Palyazo index.php file:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    

    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        
        'nev',

    
    //I would like to use the munkahely_nev field 
    // from the munkahely (4th) table

    //Without this block I'm also getting the error..
    /*

       [
            'label' => 'Munkahelyek',
            'format' => 'ntext',
            'attribute'=>'munkahely_nev',
            'value' => function($model) {
                foreach ($model->megpalyazottMunkahely as $munkahely) {
                    $munkahelyNevek[] = $munkahely->munkahely_nev;
                }
                return implode("\n", $munkahelyNevek);
            },
       ],     
    */

            ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Comment: can you add a try catch and show the complete trace of the exception , also the complete code for the models `Palyazo` & `PalyazoSearch`, just revert your code to the original one as you askde in question using `$query = Palyazo::find()->innerJoinWith('megpalyazottMunkahely', true);`

Comment: i used this schema and for me your code works correctly http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c79a6/2

Comment: Dear Muhammed Omer Aslam! I very much appreciate your help, your time.. This is the  full error message: https://pastebin.com/GX6TGsEe

Comment: add the code for the models i asked in the first comment

Comment: It would be better to edit the whole article.. I'm afraid it seems to be too difficult to read, to understand...

Comment: Please dont spend time with this Muhammad! Later I have to edit the article. Maybe it is good what Serghei suggested, still I have newer errormessage (Trying to get property of non-object)) at this line: $munkahelyNevek[] = $munkahely->munkahely_nev; But maybe I'm close to the solution.. or not :D :D Yes, I have a munkahely model too (it is generated with gii, there is no relation function inside this.)

Comment: I was not able to share my code because I had tons of variables and relations in the Palyazo model. Beside this I tried to make a clean new app with just these 4 tables but my PHP is too old to make it